# Number of Marker per cluster

Tags: angularjs, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I am using lealfet.markercluster in my project and I wonder if there is a way to set the minimum number of markers per cluster.

e.g : if the number of markers in a zone is greater then 3 it will be clustered, otherwise the marker should be displayed normally (not clustered)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature request at https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/issues/526#issuecomment-285355298 is still open, so the answer is "no".

Comment: [Leaflet.markercluster issue #399](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/issues/399) might be a a more exact match.